# Would changing my webpage's HTML content only partially affect my SEO?

Tags: seo, html, content

I have a webpage like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Document Content">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Document</h1>
    <p>Document Content</p>
    <br>
    <div id="changing">
        <span>I</span>
        <span>II</span>
        <span>III</span>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The part of `div id="changing"` has the `I - II - III` portion changing every day to different letters like `A - AA - AAA` or `B - BB - BBB`

However the `<title> - <meta name="description"> - <h1>` never change because they are the core of the page.

Would changing the values affect my SEO negatively despite that the `I - A - B` content is always related to the title?

Comment: If you're just changing a few numbers to letters but the rest of the content will remain the same, it's unlikely that will affect SEO. Content is often dynamically generated (e.g., based on geographic location), so that's to be expected. If you actually meant that a more significant amount of content will change, then please edit the question to make that clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer for your particular case is **NO**. It won't affect your SERP rankings.

**The reason is:** updating page content with better content, recent version, or adding more value to the content is a good practice in SEO.

Since updating content definitely involves addition or subtraction of HTML elements, you shouldn't worry for the HTML as well as the content itself (again, as long as it is useful and valuable content).

**Examples of Good updates covering your case:**

- daily updated gold rates in a region (same page, same description, just rates are updated)
- daily updated prayer timings (same page, same region, same description, just timings are updated)
- available or open event listings (same page, just events filtered out based on availability)

---

**When it may impact SEO?**

When you update content while the new content is irrelevant, only keyword stuffing, the new page now seems a duplicate of another page, or similar.

---

**Additional Tip**

Make use of last modified acknowledgement to search engines. Whenever you post an update (even if it is systematic), make sure the last modified date and time is also updated.